# Tether Mac's Wifi connection to phone over Bluetooth

Tags: iphone, network, wifi, bluetooth, proxy

I'm staying in a rather upmarket hotel, yet for some reason the Wifi is £7 per device per day. I got it for my Macbook, and I'm wondering if there is a way for me to share the connection to my iPod.

Normally, I'd just use internet sharing over Bluetooth, however there are certain restrictions on this network, which are causing a problem. In order for it to work, the following requirements must be met:

1. All requests from device go through Macbook
2. Device is not assigned it's own IP address
3. Device must not be visible on the network (all requests must appear as though they're from the Mac)

I'm considering several options, one of which is a local proxy through my Mac, however as far as I know it's not possible to set proxy settings over Bluetooth tethering, only Wifi.

I'm a pretty experienced server admin, so if anyone has any OSS packages or similar that have to be built from source, please do mention as I'm more than able to do it.

Comment: Ask the reception. It is possible the "upscale place" allows only one IP per device/connection. Ending up in you can only do the screen sharing.

Comment: The conditions are (I've read them to make sure I'm not breaking them) that purchasing the Wifi 'gives you access to one IP address, for the allotted time'. Hence why I'm looking to connect my phone via my Mac so it shares an address.

Comment: your mac would need two wireless networks to do this.  If the upscale place has a wired ethernet connection in the room then you could plug the MB there and use wireless to get the signal to your iPod.  [Travel Routers](http://lifehacker.com/five-best-travel-routers-1452441479) are the best solution.